# Timeout exception with salesforce.com Java SOAP API example code from 'getting started'

Tags: java, soap, salesforce

I ran through the example code from salesforce SOAP API [quick start](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_steps.htm) but all I get is a timeout error during the first login stage. I've created a developer login and generated the wsdl, and then the .jar. The program compiles. I'm currently trying it with the following example I found elsewhere:

```
import com.sforce.soap.enterprise.Connector;
import com.sforce.soap.enterprise.EnterpriseConnection;
import com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException;
import com.sforce.ws.ConnectorConfig;

public class Main {
    static final String USERNAME = "username redacted";
    static final String PASSWORD = "password redacted";
    static final String AUTH = "https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/37.0/0DF58000000L2Vm";
    static EnterpriseConnection connection;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();
        config.setUsername(USERNAME);
        config.setPassword(PASSWORD);
        config.setAuthEndpoint(AUTH);
        try {
            connection = Connector.newConnection(config);
            // display some current settings
            System.out.println("Auth EndPoint:"+config.getAuthEndpoint());
            System.out.println("Service EndPoint:"+config.getServiceEndpoint());
            System.out.println("Username: "+config.getUsername());
            System.out.println("SessionId: "+config.getSessionId());
        } catch (ConnectionException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
}
```

But when I run it it just hangs for ages and then gives a ConnectException: Connection timed out

```
com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: Failed to send request to https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/37.0/0DF58000000L2Vm
    at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.send(SoapConnection.java:121)
    at com.sforce.soap.enterprise.EnterpriseConnection.login(EnterpriseConnection.java:1207)
    at com.sforce.soap.enterprise.EnterpriseConnection.<init>(EnterpriseConnection.java:386)
    at com.sforce.soap.enterprise.Connector.newConnection(Connector.java:27)
    at Main.main(Main.java:18)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:637)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:160)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:977)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1093)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at com.sforce.ws.transport.JdkHttpTransport.connectRaw(JdkHttpTransport.java:136)
    at com.sforce.ws.transport.JdkHttpTransport.connectLocal(JdkHttpTransport.java:100)
    at com.sforce.ws.transport.JdkHttpTransport.connectLocal(JdkHttpTransport.java:95)
    at com.sforce.ws.transport.JdkHttpTransport.connect(JdkHttpTransport.java:91)
    at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.send(SoapConnection.java:95)
    ... 4 more
```

I've checked using wireshark and with my system admin that its not the firewall: the DNS lookup is correctly resolving 'login.salesforce.com' and there are definitely packages going out. What else could I be doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure this is valid URL ? try ping the ip . (use nslook up) to get the ip

Comment: @Optimuskck by correctly resolving I mean if I type in the ip that the DNS returns (that I can see in wireshark) into a web browser it correctly takes me to 'login.salesforce.com'

Comment: Typically this is because your network is configured to have to use a proxy server for outbound connections

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2` while running jar if you are using `jdk 1.7`.

Jdk 1.8 is compatible with TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 so you can use that also

I got the same issue and I resolved it by passing the httpsprotocols.

Let me know if that worked for you